Attribute value changes from false to true to false upon click. Then cypress runs into timeout-
I have a table with lots of sections. Within the sections there is a table and for each row of the table a checkbox. Upon clicking on the checkbox the following attribute 'data-e2e-table-loading' changes from false to true, and after reloading, back to false:
Before clicking the checkbox:
<table data-e2e-table="section3" data-e2e-table-loading="false">

Shortly after clicking the checkbox:
<table data-e2e-table="section3" data-e2e-table-loading="true">

Then after reload and back to false:
<table data-e2e-table="section3" data-e2e-table-loading="false">

I am trying to catch this so it waits for 'data-e2e-table-loading="false"' But my code doe snot always work whatever I try. In this example I tried with the package: cy.waitUntil
cy.section(this.tableName).within(() => {
      cy.waitUntil(() => cy.get('[data-e2e-table-loading]', { timeout: 8000 })
        .should('be.lengthOf', 1)
        .invoke('attr', 'data-e2e-table-loading')
        .then((load) => Boolean(load)));
      cy.get('[data-e2e-table-loading="false"]').should('be.lengthOf', 1);
});

But it fails with:

get[data-e2e-table-loading="false"]
assertexpected { Object (length, prevObject, ...) } to have a length of 1 but got 0

I thought with ".should('be.lengthOf', 1)" it waits until this true. But if the sections reloads this is totally off.
I also tried this:
cy.get('[data-e2e-table-loading]').should('not.have.value',true);
cy.get('[data-e2e-table-loading]').should('have.value',false);

Does not work!
>get[data-e2e-table-loading]
>assertexpected <table.MuiTable-root.css-1dzuc3y> not to have value true

>get[data-e2e-table-loading]
>assertexpected <table.MuiTable-root.css-1dzuc3y> to have value false, but the value was '' FAIL Timout.

Also, the following code shows really weird, that in the if statement it recognizes the tag "table[data-e2e-table-loading" and after not anymore. How could that be???
waitForTableLoaded(): this {
    cy.log(`Wait for table to be loaded: ${this.tableName}`);
    cy.contains('div[data-e2e-section]',this-tableName).within((loading) => {
      if (loading.find('table[data-e2e-table-loading="false"]').length) {
        cy.log('Found loading false');
        cy.get('table[data-e2e-table-loading]')
          .should('have.attr', '[data-e2e-table-loading]', 'false');
      } else if (loading.find('table[data-e2e-table-loading="true"]').length) {
        cy.log('Found loading true. Waiting to become false');
        cy.get('table[data-e2e-table-loading]')
          .should('have.attr', '[data-e2e-table-loading]', 'false');
      } else {
        cy.wait(2000);
      }
    });
    return this;
  }

Thanks for looking at it.
((Cypress 13.14.1; Chrome))

What does cy.section(this.tableName) do? I suspect it finds [data-e2e-table="section3"] but then obviously you can't use .within() since [data-e2e-table-loading] is on the same element.

Sorry, my bad of not explaining it properly: it is like this. > div[e2e-section] table[data-e2e-loading]. At least you confirm that it should work like this.

It's not too hard from what I can see. You want to check the value of an attribute of an element, for which you want .invoke('attr', 'data-e2e-table-loading') command.
Attribute values are always string types, even if the string looks like a Boolean.
cy.get('[data-e2e-table-loading]')
  .invoke('attr', 'data-e2e-table-loading')
  .should('eq', 'true');

cy.get('[data-e2e-table-loading]')
  .invoke('attr', 'data-e2e-table-loading')
  .should('eq', 'false');

Or I guess a second way would be to let should extract the attribute
cy.get('[data-e2e-table-loading]')
  .should('have.attr', '[data-e2e-table-loading]', 'true');

cy.get('[data-e2e-table-loading]')
  .should('have.attr', '[data-e2e-table-loading]', 'false');


Thank you for you input! I had it with [data-e2e-table-loading="false"]).should('be.lengthOf',1) It did not work. Also yours seem to not work in this case.

I tried this:
cy.section(this.tableName).within((loading) => {
if (loading.find('table[data-e2e-table-loading="true"]').length) {
cy.log('Found loading true. Waiting to become false');
cy.get('[data-e2e-table-loading]')
.should('have.attr', '[data-e2e-table-loading]', 'false');
}
But it does not find data-e2e-table-loading in after the IF statement!!
